# Sistema em PHP responder em Partes

Tags: php

Vi que é possível fazer um sistema em PHP que responde em partes, não apliquei, mas basicamente seria usar esta função:

`ob_implicit_flush()`

Assim qualquer saída seria enviada diretamente para o navegador do browser, ao contrário de esperar o sistema finalizar para enviar tudo para saída.

Bom, isto tem grandes impactos em desempenho, isso poderia ser ruim de alguma forma?

A ideia é listar produtos, e ir imprimindo conforme o PHP der a saída(echo), assim daria para ver alguns produtos sem precisar que todos fossem processados para sucessivamente dar a saída.

Answer (score 3):

Do ponto de vista de uma conexão TCP, não há nenhum problema. O que acontece quando você envia a resposta em partes, ao invés de uma única resposta, é que a camada de transporte cria um *buffer* com os dados e só os dispara quando ordenado (ou seja, quando ocorre uma chamada `ob_flush`, por exemplo).

Acredito que o maior problema dessa prática seja a experiência do usuário, pois pode ser algo frustrante a página ir carregando, carregando, e não chegar no final do carregamento nunca. A não ser que você adote uma barra de progresso ou lhe dê algum tipo de *feedback*.

Também é importante tentar diagnosticar o gargalo, ou seja, porque a página está demorando tanto para carregar. Talvez seja uma boa diagnosticar suas consultas SQL, arquivos estáticos (CSS, JS), tamanho do HTML, dentre outros aspectos.